# After upgrading to WordPress v5.1 anchor tag automatically appeared n-times in edit page

Tags: html, wordpress

For Example:

In previous version my HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="value-holder FL">
   <img src="abc.jpg" alt="" class="flag">
   <a href="xyz.pdf" target="_blank"><h2> Product Brochure (German) </h2></a>
</div>
```

After Upgrading to WordPress v5.1 my HTML code automatically changed to:

```
<div class="value-holder FL">
   <img src="abc.jpg" alt="" class="flag">
   <a href="xyz.pdf" target="_blank"><h2> Product Brochure (German) </h2></a>
   <a href="xyz.pdf" target="_blank"><h2> Product Brochure (German) </h2></a>
   <a href="xyz.pdf" target="_blank"><h2> Product Brochure (German) </h2></a>
</div>
```

Notice those extra anchors tags appearing automatically.

One more thing I have noticed that whenever I click on "Update" it adds one more anchor tag to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Notice you didn't close your anchor. Try to change your HTML to:

```
<div class="value-holder FL">
   <img src="abc.jpg" alt="" class="flag">
   <a href="xyz.pdf" target="_blank"><h2> Product Brochure (German) </h2></a>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh! my bad, anchor is already there, I unknowingly erased it. now the question is corrected. thanks for noticing it.